# How much power and lift margin do helicopters have for hover?

Tags: helicopter, rotorcraft, rotor-head, flight-envelope

Suppose you are designing a helicopter and trying to size the rotor system for hover and flight. Your helicopter has a certain gross weight at sea level, standard atmosphere. How much additional lift margin do you design into the lift system? Or worded another way, how much margin do you add to a flight envelope?

Since there is ample information on the Robinson R44, let's consider:
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_R44) says:
Gross Weight: 2500 lbs (1134 kg)
Rotor Diameter: 10m
Powerplant: 245 hp (183 kW)
In theory this is at Sea Level, Standard Atmosphere.

But would there be additional rotor lift margin for the helicopter's rotor to be able to maneuver, and for safety? For example, I imagine the R44 would actually be capable of lifting 3000 lbs (suppose) at sea level, and with the 183kW, but this is derated to 2500 lbs for operational safety. I'm not talking about the structural safety margins for the components, for which the FARs are pretty clear in general, I'm after the aerodynamic forces here.

Given my experience flying, I don't expect it to be much, but curious to see if there is any reference/standard/custom. Thanks!

Comment: Key here is density altitude, and weight.  There will be charts and graphs in the POH for this.

Comment: Civil helicopter certification requires stall-free operations at 1.15g and mtow. This should be the value you're looking for. Anyway the design of the main rotor is much more complicated than that and fundamentally dependent on the customer requirements and/or intended use.

Comment: Let me know if my comment answers your question, if so I'll convert it into a proper answer

Comment: Hi sophit, yes that was the answer I was looking for!